# Kafka topic returns 0 messages

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-topic

I have a real-time process that streams events occuring in MongoDB directly to Snowflake using Confluent Platform. Confluent is established on my local machine as a docker image and I see no issues:

```
     Name                    Command                  State                         Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
broker            /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
connect           /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp, 9092/tcp
control-center    /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp
ksql-datagen      bash -c echo Waiting for K ...   Up
ksqldb-cli        /bin/sh                          Up
ksqldb-server     /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp
rest-proxy        /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp
schema-registry   /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp
zookeeper         /etc/confluent/docker/run        Up             0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Everything was working over last days and today I re-ran my process with powershell:

`docker-compose exec broker bash` and `kafka-console-consumer --topic <MY_TOPIC> --bootstrap-server broker:9092`

I noticed that when I insert data to Mongo's collection Kafka topic doesn't see it, instead returns `Processed a total of 0 messages`

How to debug what is going on? Connection passwords, topics are all set correctly and I don't know where to start debugging.

I used to get below result but now it's idle:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, in Confluent Control Center `Connect` tab check setting for source connector.

For my mongo's connection, new URI syntax fixed the issue (the one where you don't point database, that is done in seperate tab)

[image]